# Issues with itemizing using a latex pandoc template

Tags: formatting, itemize, templates, loops, pandoc

I have tried looking around everywhere and could not find a solution to this issue. I have created a Latex template that is compatible with pandoc. For some reason whenever I enter another for loop and try to itemize the variables the error I get is the following:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.118           \item\small
```

The latex snippet responsible for producing this error is this

```latex
$if(experience)$
\section{Experience}
    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
         $for(experience)$
              \resumeSubheading
               {$experience.title$}{$experience.dates$}
               {$experience.company$} {$experience.location$}
              $if(experience.details)$
               \begin{itemize}
               $for(experience.details)$
                     \item\small{$experience.details$ \vspace{-2pt}}
               $endfor$
               \end{itemize}
               $endif$
          $endfor$
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
 $endif$
```

`resumeSubHeadingListStart` and `resumeSubHeadingListEnd` are custom commands that do the following:

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
```

However, creating a regular `\item` element is possible but the bullets are missing.

The latex output looks like this

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\input{glyphtounicode}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt,before=\leavevmode\vspace{-5pt}}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}


\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[1]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small#1  \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}


\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemii{\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny\bullet}}}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge \scshape Latex Fan} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small +1-646-333-3333 | \href{mailto:template@gmail.com}{\underline{template@gmail.com}} |
    \href{test.xyz}{\underline{test.xyz}} |
    \href{https://github.com/test}{\underline{test}}
\end{center}

\section{Experience}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
\resumeSubheading
  {ML Engineer}{Sep 2019 -- Current}
  {Some Company} {New York, NY}
    \begin{itemize} 
          \item\small{Developed and deployed a recommendation system
that applies reinforcement learning on a set of web page components to
discover the most optimal permutation based on the implicit user
feedback in near real time. \vspace{-2pt}}
          \item\small{Designed and implemented an even driven
architecture of the system as a decoupled monolith consisting of a
number of bounded contexts using principles of domain driven design and
clean architecture. \vspace{-2pt}}
      \end{itemize}
  \resumeSubheading
  {Quantitative Analyst}{2019 -- 2019}
  {Some Company} {New York, NY}
    \begin{itemize} 
          \item\small{Created a set of notebooks with quantitative
models for portfolio optimization, price forecasting, and hedging to
generate an optimal asset composition strategy. These tools assisted in
devising an index composition and launch of an ETF
product. \vspace{-2pt}}
          \item\small{Built an ETL pipeline to operate on various
financial and alternative data from internal sources as well as 3rd
party APIs. Also, set up a PostreSQL data warehouse for aggregating the
processed data for future analysis. \vspace{-2pt}}
          \item\small{Developed a dashboard for data visualization and
monitoring the performance of major world indices. \vspace{-2pt}}
      \end{itemize}
  \resumeSubheading
  {Research Engineer}{2018 -- 2019}
  {Other Office} {New York, NY}
    \begin{itemize} 
          \item\small{Developed quantimental strategies for price
forecasting and discovery of asymmetric information of various assets in
the public markets. \vspace{-2pt}}
          \item\small{Worked on bringing well-performing experimental
strategies into production by optimizing the existing code, rewriting
trading signal components in C++ and integrating them with legacy
services. \vspace{-2pt}}
          \item\small{Developed a module for integration with a
backtesting engine to simulate and test the performance of experimental
trading strategies. \vspace{-2pt}}
      \end{itemize}
  \resumeSubheading
  {Jr.~Partner}{2016 -- 2018}
  {Some Fund} {New York, NY}
    \begin{itemize} 
          \item\small{Researched the use cases for distributed ledger
technology and the development on Bitcoin, Ethereum, and EOS
networks. \vspace{-2pt}}
          \item\small{Developing services to process user transactions
and staking tokens on EOS and Ethereum networks for a recruitment
dApp. \vspace{-2pt}}
      \end{itemize}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
      \resumeSubheading
    {Some School}{Philadelphia, PA}
    {Some Degree}{2100 -- 2104}
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you show the final LaTeX code for the snippet that is produced by the template (with the loop unfolded and the variables instantiated)? Also, `\small` is a switch, not a command with an argument, so the `{}` are not needed here - however that should not influence the result.

Comment: I have updated the main post with the procedures that come before itemization

Comment: Thank you for the update, this is not what I intended though. The error will be easier to spot when you show the generated LaTeX code that is eventually processed, instead of the template code. Pandoc can produce this LaTeX code if you set the target to `.tex` instead of `.pdf`.

Comment: Oh I see, I have incorporated the updates into the question. Let me know if this is what you were referring to

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the fragment you show, which probably means that the error is *before* this part. The reported line number is just the point at which TeX gets confused but isn't necessarily where the actual error is. Have you checked for any stray underscores or carets in the text, for example? Unrelated, but instead of a negative `\vspace` you should set the `itemsep` parameter properly for the list.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error and indeed with the output as given there is no problem. That means that you should provide a bigger example of the generated LaTeX code, preferably the complete document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Of course if it is your CV then you can anonymize and reduce the content to keep the example code small, as long as it still reproduces the error. Indeed `_` and `^` characters in the text are common reasons for this kind of error.

Comment: Hm let me experiment with that, also I have update the main question with the fully generated latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have redefined `\labelitemii` to use `\bullet` which is a mathmode command:

```
\renewcommand\labelitemii{\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny\bullet}}}
```

A better replacement would be:

```
\renewcommand\labelitemii\raisebox{.3ex}{\tiny\textbullet}
```

But even better would be to use `enumitem` methods instead:

```
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\raisebox{.3ex}{\tiny\textbullet}}
```

Also, you shouldn't be using negative `\vspace{}` commands anywhere. For list items, use the `nosep` key of `enumitem` instead to control list spacing. Similarly you can use the `before` key to add the `\small` command to change font size before the list items.

Comment: After implementing the `enumitem` suggestion all the issues have gone away. Greatly appreciate your suggestion!

Comment: @BGLD If this answer solved your problem it’s helpful to others to “accept” it by clicking on the green check mark beside the answer.